# Disable key-pressing in MessageDialog

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with my software developped in Java. The user has to write a text in a JtextPane. When there's no time left for him to write, a pop-up appears. 
The only problem is : if the user is writting when the message pops up, the pop-up disappears because the key pressed validate the message.

Is there's anyway I can disable this fonction ?
I use this to create the MessageDialog :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                new UTIL_LireFichierTXT().getText(MessageTempsImparti)
                ,new UTIL_LireFichierTXT().getText(MessageAttention),JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `the pop-up disappears because the key pressed validate the message.` - that doesn't make sense to me. In general, typing a key will not close a dialog (except when using the Enter key or the Space Bar). Maybe the problem is that you use "null" for the parent frame. I don't see any reason for not displaying a popup dialog when the time limit is up. I would suggest the problem is with the code you didn't post. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You're right. (sorry if I don't speak clearly but I'm a french student, still learning English..) . The pop-up disappears when you press space or enter. But when you are writting a text, you often use the space bar... So the user doesn't see the pop-up :/

Comment: I tried my code in a main, It did the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling normal application behaviour (such as manipulation of dialogs with keys) is not a great idea. It confuses a lot of users, who have been groomed to expect certain core functionality in GUIs, plus it can prove a real problem for users with disabilities, who may need to use keyboard navigation in place of a mouse.

I would suggest you consider a different method of telling the user the time is up. Perhaps a banner label appearing on the application somewhere?